# where can I download cryptography windows 7 64 bit installer

Tags: python-2.7

Scrapy is really difficult library on the Windows. There are many dependencies. 
I am wasting lots of time to find those things. And now, I need cryptography. But, where is the installer ? I tried installing pip install or easy_install. but failed. Where can I download the installer for the Windows 7 64bit?

```
D:\workspace\python\scrapy-install-151214>pip install cryptography
Collecting cryptography
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cryptography (from ver
sions: )
No matching distribution found for cryptography
```

I tried instaling thiis library as a whl file. but it failed like the followings.

```
D:\workspace\python\scrapy-install-151214>pip install cryptography-0.7.2-cp27-no
ne-win_amd64.whl
cryptography-0.7.2-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this plat
form.
```

Comment: probably your version of python and cryptography does not match. check the python version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried installing from this [source](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography). it worked for me without any glitch.

Pythong version `Python 2.7.10 [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`
Cryptography wheel file `cryptography-1.1.2-cp27-none-win32.whl`

choose whose the wheel file by the following

1. Based Platform `windows|linux|macintosh` version, since you are
   using windows choose wheel file what contains `win`.
2. Choose the bit version based on your python bit version. if it is 64
   choose a file that contains `64` else `32`.

Comment: Thanks I had never tried this one. because It has name end with "32". I went through thanks to you. :)